# Geometry - Solve a system of equations (maybe using WA or another CAS)

Tags: calculus, geometry, systems-of-equations, area

I found this problem on the web, and it seemed like an interesting exercise to me.

[image: math001]

So I am trying to solve this as a system of equations.

I tried using for example Wolfram Alpha.

That means e.g. I am trying to find the radius $R$ of the circle, and the point $x$, where the two curves touch each other.

I was hoping at least for a numeric solution. But I don't get anything  useful.

Could anyone help to get this working in WA?

I am not sure why WA doesn't understand this syntax.

```
Solve[Exp(-x^2) * (-2*x) == (R-x) / sqrt(x * (2*R-x)) && Exp(-x^2) == R + sqrt(x * (2*R-x)) && x > R && x < 2*R, {x, R}, Reals]
```

How did I get these equations? Well, I think they should give me the solution to this problem above. Why? Because they express that

$f(x) = g(x)$  and also $f'(x) = g'(x)$

where the radius is denoted by $R$.

Here I have denoted

$$f(x) = e^{-x^2}$$
$$g(x) = R + \sqrt{x(2R-x)}$$

($g$ is the top semi-circle basically)

and I am looking for a solution $x$, where $x \in (R, 2R)$

I hope I didn't mess any calculations... but I think I didn't.
The two derivatives are easy to calculate.
So I am not sure why WA doesn't understand this.

**EDIT**:

I am not sure if any of the solutions below is actually an exact/explicit solution. I think I didn't get any formula for the blue area or for the touch point.

This is not a Mathematica stack exchange question actually. Mathematica was used just as a means to solve the problem. I am actually looking for a formula for the blue area (or for the X value of the touch point). I constructed a system of equations but solving by hand wasn't possible. Is there such formula, or do we have to use numeric approximations here? I think both answers here provide just a numeric approximation.

Comment: Have you tried the Mathematica specific exchange? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza No, I didn't know it existed. Also, I don't have Mathematica, just the web page WA https://www.wolframalpha.com/. I don't know. But in general my approach is correct, right?

Comment: Does it just want to find the area of the blue area that’s tangent to axes and equation? I’m not sure I understand what it means by max

Comment: The idea is you can have different circles there but only one touches the graph and the axes has max area. At least that is how I understand it.

Comment: Ok, i'll see what i can do with this

Comment: I’m voting to close this question belongs to mathematica stackexchange.

Answer (score 4):

HINT.- $(1)\space f(x)=e^{-x^2}$

$(2)$ The circle has radius $a$ and center $(a,a)$.

$(3)$ Tangent to this circle coincides with the tangent to $f(x)$ at some point $(x_0,y_0)$ so its equation is $\dfrac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=-2x_0f(x_0)$.

$(4)$ Line perpendicular to this tangent allows us to finish.

Note.-You can have $a\approx 0.38$ (see the center pointed in attached figure)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. On your drawing it looks like the circle touches the graph in the inflection point of the graph i.e. at $x=1/\sqrt{2}\ $ Is this true or it just looks that way? Btw, what software did you use to generate this nice drawing?

Comment: @peter.petrov https://desmos.com/calculator :)

Comment: Thanks. OK, I see the touch point is not the inflection point.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this problem I initially thought was not that bad, but then I couldnt reason through all the logic and i got mad so i made it my personal vandetta to solve this using any method possible, so apologies if this is inefficient. You can probably salvage a faster method through this mess lol.

First, notice the circle is touching both coordinate axes, meaning its center will lie directly on the line $y=x$. WLOG let the equation of the circle be $$(x-r)^2+(y-r)^2=r^2$$
We can graphically see that we need the top part of the circle

[image]

Set this equal to our bounding equation so we have $$e^{-x^2}=\sqrt{r^2-(x-r)^2}+r$$

Now let's find another equation. If we draw the tangent line at the point where the circle meets the bounding equation we see that

[image]

By the distance formula, the distance from the point of tangency is $\sqrt{x^2+e^{-2x^2}}$. By adding up the radii, we see that this is equivalent to $r+r\sqrt2$. Setting these two equal to one another gives us a system of equations. (I just assumed the point the tangent point will lie on $y=x$, which is a good enough approximation. i will find an exact solution later)

\begin{align*}
e^{-x^2}&=\sqrt{r^2-(x-r)^2}+r\\
r+r\sqrt2&=\sqrt{x^2+e^{-2x^2}}
\end{align*}

Rewrite the second equation into $$r=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+e^{-2x^2}}}{1+\sqrt2}$$
and substitute it back into the first equation, we get (I did a FullSimplify on the substituted result first)

```
NSolve[((-1 + Sqrt[2]) (Sqrt[E^(-2 x^2) + x^2] + Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[2]] Sqrt[-(x (x + Sqrt[2] x - 2 Sqrt[E^(-2 x^2) + x^2]))]))==E^(-x^2), x]
```

$$x\approx0.65292...$$

Hence the radius is

```
N[Sqrt[0.65292^2 + E^(-2 0.65292^2)]/(1 + Sqrt[2])]
```

$$r\approx 0.38247...$$

And the area of the circle would be
$$\pi r^2\approx0.4595648...$$

---

In hindsight to approximate the point of tangency I literally could have done

```
Reduce[x==E^(-x^2)]
```

to get

[image]

which saves me from wasting all that computing time on the much more complicated reduce but whatever

Comment: Thank you. "In hindsight to find the point of tangency I literally could have done" >>> Why? Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @peter.petrov Before that i had remarked "I just assumed the point the tangent point will lie on y=x, idk if you should show this is rigorouly true?" which i graphically assumed to be true. If this is the case, the fact that the tangency point lies on the same intersection as $x=e^{-x^2}$ naturally follows

Comment: But it doesn't seem to be true (from the drawing in the other answer here - the one by Piquito). Right? Or are you saying "OK, let's just make some approximation and assume it's true"? I mean, it's close but not really true, right?

Comment: @peter.petrov I used an approximation for that yea. I'll look into this more and see if i can come up with something better tho lol

Comment: You don't need to. Thanks a lot! Both answers have been great help. I just need to rethink it all now myself. So I just wanted a confirmation here if you used a slight approximation, or you actually claimed that the touch point lies on y=x. It could be also that the drawing in the other answer is not quite perfect, and maybe that claim is true indeed. I don't know yet. Interesting problem.